# Pros and cons of a brass hip flask

Tags: flavor, alcohol, storage

I have been considering buying a hip flask for some time now. I have been holding off from getting the cheap varieties because I hear they impart a metallic taste to the alcohol. If I had my druthers, I would get a pewter flask, but I can't justify the cost.

A couple of weeks ago I happened upon a brass flask. The cost is between the cheaper ones and a pewter flask. From this price point, I would assume the quality to be somewhere between the two. I have not been able to find any literature about brass flasks.

Does anyone have some information on them?

Comment: um ... pewter contains lead.  I would think that'd be the last thing you'd want to be putting consumables in.

Comment: @Joe - Pewter should contain nearly zero lead these days, but I certainly agree caution is warranted, especially with antique models. There are some differences in opinion about the health/safety remaining metals (e.g., tin) -- more at [this related Beer.SE question](http://beer.stackexchange.com/questions/351/drinking-from-a-pewter-mug).

Comment: Brass *also often contains lead.* Modern pewter mostly does not, old pewter may well....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a lot depends on your use of the flask, but there are some considerations.

**Aesthetics:** Brass is likely to corrode and/or get a nice patina, so that could be a nice effect. You're not going to get the same effect from a chrome-plated or stainless flask.

**Health:** Copper, a major compoenent of brass, [can be toxic in quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper_toxicity) -- especially with acid contact. You certainly don't want to put anything acidic in the thing -- certainly keep your margaritas and daiquiris away from it! In any case, I wouldn't store beverages of any kind in brass for an extended period due to oxidation or other corrosion. Copper [lined] stills are still common, so it's unlikely that alcohol itself is particularly bad for copper. Further, nothing besides booze is meant for the inside of a flask anyway. :)

**Maintenance:** Brass will corrode and you'll need to keep it more well-maintained (specifically on the inside) than other materials.

**Durability:** In my opinion and experience, I have seen cheaper (e.g., chrome-plated) flasks corrode at joints/seams and get at least unsightly and perhaps unhealthy. Brass should be more durable than that, especially if properly [joined/brazed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazing).

For my money, I personally like high-quality formed stainless steel... though there are certainly pro/con tradeoffs for stainless also.

Comment: Stainless is the best bet if going there. Checking which local laws you may be violating and not going there may be a better option - it's patently illegal to have a flask of alcohol in a vehicle (or the passenger compartment thereof) in many jurisdictions. It's not uncommonly a violation to have one on a public street, sidewalk, park etc. The usual terminology is "other than the manufacturer's original unopened container"